# How cookie is work on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am just trying to understand the thing like how cookies work for mobile browser.

When we set cookies without expiration time then cookies get clear/deleted when desktop browser is closed.

for that we are using

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

but not getting clear about how cookies get clear/deleted on mobile because there is no way to close browser on mobile.

is there any default cookie expiration time on mobile ? or cookies get clear automatically after sometime on mobile ?

Comment: *"there is no way to close browser on mobile."* [Yes there is...](http://www.howtogeek.com/211166/how-to-force-quit-an-application-on-any-smartphone-computer-or-tablet/)

Comment: Have you tested that? If so, How? Update the question.

Comment: yes, i have tested this by removing recently used app from mobile

Comment: Which mobile browser you use?

Comment: i have tested this on chrome(Android phone)

Comment: Cookie is browser thing, not device, and depends only on browser type/version, and you should check it by yourself, +1 for info, but maybe try to use localStorage (they don't get cleared on browser close)?